# A question in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

What is the possible number of ways in which 8 digit numbers can be made from 1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4 such that odd numbers do not occupy odd places ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no odd digits can be placed on odd places, you must fill all odd places with even digits. There are four odd places, and you've got four even digits ($2$, $2$, $4$, $4$), so they are just enough to fill the four odd slots. The number of ways to do so is
$$n_{\text{odd places}} = \frac{4!}{2!\cdot 2!} = 6.$$
Now you have to fill the even places. Since you've used up all even digits for the odd places, you have to fill the even places with the odd digits, $1$, $1$, $1$, $3$. It is quite obvious that there are four possibilities to do so, since all you can decide is where to put the $3$, and then fill the rest with $1$. But you can also calculate this mechanically:
$$n_{\text{even places}} = \frac{4!}{3!\cdot 1!} = 4.$$
Now it turns out that the filling of odd and even places is independent of each other (this would have been different if, e.g., you would have had three each of $2$ and of $4$, and only two odd  digits). For this reason you find the total number of possibilities by just multiplying both numbers:
$$n_{\text{total}} = n_{\text{odd places}}\cdot n_{\text{even places}} = 6\cdot 4 = 24.$$

Answer (score 1):

So you have four odd numbers. They must occupy slots $2, 4, 6, 8$. So you permute $\{1, 1, 1, 3\}$. There are $\dfrac{4!}{3!}$ ways to do this by the multinomial distribution.

Now we permute $\{2, 2, 4, 4\}$ in slots $1, 3, 5, 7$. There are $\dfrac{4!}{2! * 2!}$ ways to do this by the multinomial distribution.

By rule of product, we multiply: $\dfrac{4! * 4!}{3! * 2! * 2!}$.

Comment: But answer is 16. So I am confused.

Comment: Someone else just confirmed my answer, so I think you have an incorrect answer with $16$.